# AWS EC2: Moving /var to EBS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos, plesk

I'm banging my head against a wall for the last 5 hours or so.

I have a brand new Centos 6 installation with Plesk. Once the machine is booted up I'm trying to move the `/var` folder to an attached EBS (`/dev/xvdj`):

```
#copy original /var to /dev/xvdj
mkdir /mnt/new
mount /dev/xvdj /mnt/new
cd /var
cp -Rax * /mnt/new
cd /
mv var var.old
#mount EBS as new /var
umount /dev/xvdj
mkdir /var
mount /dev/xvdj /var
```

I know prior to moving `/var` I'm supposed to boot the instance into runlevel 1 (single user) to prevent anything writing and reading from `/var`. However, this locks me out from the instance which I learned the hard way.

I tried to manually stop mysql, webserver and mail server, but after I move `/var` I can't bring these services back up, they just state `[FAILED]` when I attempt to start. They also don't write anything into `/var/log`. On a first glance permission of the directories inside `/var` look alright, symlinks exist too.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should find that the syslogs are still going to /old.var/log unless you stop and start the syslog service.  Renaming a directory does not change anything about files under it that are already open -- they will still be open, at the new path, until closed by the process that had them open.  Also, did you stop MySQL, et al, *before* copying the files?

Comment: Ok, thanks. This explains the missing mysql log - will have a look in var.old.  Yes, I did stop MySQL and the other services *before* moving. Any idea how I can stop *everything* before moving? You mentioned syslog, there are probably others too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do that is probably offline. Detach your EBS disks from the first instance, attach to another one, mount them and make the changes, including the *fstab* of the root EBS. Then, detach and attach it again on the original instance and boot. I would do that way.

Comment: That's a great idea, next time I'll try this. I ended up finding the issue though - Selinux was enabled and prevented all kind of things from running at a different location other than /var! After trying to get selinux working I figured this would be a non trivial job. so I [switched it off](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/sec-sel-enable-disable.html). Not great for security I guess, but at lease my setup works now. Also, instead of the entire `/var` I linked vhosts, mysql, mail and psa dumps to individual directories on the EBS.

Comment: pre-systemd I'd just do it in sort-of-single user after stopping almost everything, but systemd makes this difficult. This is the best advice, above.

Answer (score 7):

This is a very common requirement for all corporate clients, having separate partition does help a lot in order to increase volume size at any given point of time.

**Most of the people get stuck with SSH connection problem after doing partitioning that's when they use a more generalized approach to do partitioning.**

**I have specially written a blog for this with a detail step by step procedure to perform such operation on AWS EBS.**

[Steps to create separate /var partition on AWS EBS volume](http://bhargavamin.com/how-to-do/create-separate-var-partition-ebs-volume-aws/)

**Also if you choose to do partitioning using LVM then here is one more post which has detailed step by step procedure with screenshots.**

[Create root swap and LVM partition on AWS EBS volume](http://bhargavamin.com/how-to-do/create-root-swap-lvm-partition-ebs-volume-aws/)

Hope this helps! :)